What does it mean when a systematic strategy yields significantly different backtesting results with minimal changes to the backtesting starting date?
I am testing a simple systematic strategy: I buy a certain product once every five business days and sell it after three business days from the buy date.
In the backtest, this is how I define my strategy: I shift the starting date of the strategy by $5$ business days to find the days on which I will buy and by $5+3$ business days to find the days on which I will sell what I bought.
I have noticed that I can get very different cumulative PNL profiles by just shifting the starting day from $T$ to $T+1$, $T+2$, $T+3$, and $T+4$ (a shift to $T+5$ days is the same as starting on the original day $T$, minus one initial trade, so the shape of the cumulative PNL is practically identical——I am backtesting over periods of at least one year, hence with at least ~50 trades).
I am aware that I could formalise the strategy differently:

I could always buy e. g. on Mondays and sell on Thursdays for every week.
But I am curious to understand the results that I get with keeping fixed the frequency of $5$ business days with which I buy, rather than always buying on the same day of each week, because I do not want the specificity of the day of the week on which I trade to be part of the strategy.

I could run the strategy in a starting-day independent way by aggregating the strategies that buy every $5$ business days starting on day $T$, day $T+1$, day $T+2$, day $T+3$ and day $T+4$.
But I want to implement a strategy with the constraint of not placing more than one buy trade per $5$ business days. Hence I want to know how to interpret the variance among the cumulative PNLs of the strategy performed on different starting days ($T$, $T+1$, $T+2$, $T+3$ and $T+4$).
How would you analyse the variance among the cumulative PNLs arising from small changes in the starting day? If high, would you discard the strategy? Are you aware of anywhere in the literature where these phenomena are discussed?


